# How to create a sql query to find time length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find out how long something has been down. I have a `DateTime` field called DateAndTime.  I want to find out how long from time of recording to time it stops so say it records from 8:00:00 to 8:00:12 (series 1) then 12:00:13 to 12:02:16 (series 2) etc. How can I write in my query to find the difference between the last value it records for that series and the first for that series. Here is what I have now. I am not sure what direction to go in when solving this problem using solely sql.

```
SELECT DateAndTime 
FROM ProductTracker 
WHERE LineFaultStatus = 1 
    AND DateAndTime > '2014-04-07 8:00:00' 
    AND DateAndTime < '2014-04-07 17:00:00'
```

It returns every instance of where LineFault is true or 1 from 8 a.m. to 5 p.m. which is what it is suppose to do. But I need for it to count each series and give me a time total for each.  Any help to get me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the requested data

```
2014-04-07 08:00:01.000
2014-04-07 08:00:02.000
2014-04-07 08:00:03.000
2014-04-07 08:00:04.000
2014-04-07 08:00:05.000
2014-04-07 08:00:06.000
2014-04-07 08:00:07.000
2014-04-07 08:00:08.000
2014-04-07 08:00:09.000
2014-04-07 08:00:10.000
2014-04-07 09:44:30.000
2014-04-07 09:44:31.000
2014-04-07 09:44:32.000
2014-04-07 09:44:33.000
2014-04-07 09:44:34.000
2014-04-07 09:44:35.000
2014-04-07 09:44:36.000
2014-04-07 09:44:37.000
2014-04-07 09:44:38.000
```

Comment: do you have a start date and end date columns? if you could provide table ProductTracker example data it would be a great information.

Comment: oh and no it is based of DateAndTime comparing values passed to it

Comment: OK no worries. LoL i see your profile, it seem u like to create question and answer it by yourself. hehehehe

Comment: @cyan what do you mean?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the tag of the database you are using.  In addition, your query references a field `LineFaultStatus` that is not in the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Line fault status is 0 or 1 it's bit true or false.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is DateAndTime column data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the `lag` function and some logic to determine where each sequence begins.  Then, you can use cumulative sum to get the information about each group.

```
select min(DateAndTime) as minDateAndTime, max(DateAndTime) as maxDateAndTime
from (select pt.*,
             sum(case when datediff(second, prevdt, DateAndTime) <= 1 then 0 else 1 end) over 
                 (order by DateAndTime) as grp
      from (select pt.*, lag(DateAndTime) over (order by DateAndTime) as prevdt
            from ProductTracker pt
            where LineFaultStatus = 1 and
                  DateAndTime > '2014-04-07 8:00:00' and
                  DateAndTime < '2014-04-07 17:00:00'
           ) pt
     ) pt
group by grp
order by 1;
```

Comment: Suppose to show my min and max date as same date and time?

Comment: Just replicates the data but says minDateAndTime, maxDateAndTime as column header.

Comment: Didn't work right the first time I tried it. Thank you!